# View rendering in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am using spring-boot in a basic website. I have a `home.html` page which is returned by `HomeController`, and other pages which are loaded as `iframe` in `home.html` page through navigation on the home page. I want `personal.html` page is loaded as `iframe` of `home.html` page only after successful login from `login.html` page. Again `login.html` page is loaded as `iframe` in  `home.html`.

The mystery is: After an authentication check from my request handler function (request is posted by `login.html`) when I return 'personal.html' as view in `ModelAndView` object, it automatically sits inside `iframe` of `home.html`.I was expecting 'personal.html' will replace `home.html`. Although this is what I wanted, I didn't understand why this happened.

Following is part of `home.html`.

```
<body>
    <div>
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="#home"     id="id_home"  onClick='changePage(event);' class="active">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#persoal"  id="id_personal" onClick='changePage(event);'>Personal</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="login">
        <a href="#login" id="id_login" onClick='setNewPage(event);'>login</a>
    </div>

    <div>
        <iframe id="anchor" src = "${iframe_source}"></iframe>
    </div>
</body>
```

See code snippet below of my request handler function (Working code, how? - Shouldn't `personal.html` replace `home.html`?):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/html/login",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView getPersonalPage(@RequestParam("userName") String username,
        @RequestParam("password") String password)
{
    if(userService.authenticateUser(username, password) == true)
    {
        ModelAndView modelView = new ModelAndView();
        modelView.setViewName("personal");
        modelView.addObject("user", username);
        return modelView;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Actually, I was thinking it will work by following code (But not working, why? - Shuouldn't `personal.html` be loaded as `iframe` in `home.html`?).

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/html/login",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView getPersonalPage(@RequestParam("userName") String username,
        @RequestParam("password") String password)
{
     if(userService.authenticateUser(username, password) == true)
     {
         ModelAndView modelView = new ModelAndView();
         modelView.setViewName("home");
         modelView.addObject("user", username);
         modelView.addObject("iframe_src",
            "personal.html");
         return modelView;
     }
     else
     {
         return null;
     }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you're actually asking here? Without the commented-out code, is it working as you want? Showing two versions of the code will make it more clear than leaving in commented-out code. Also, providing a little more code context (what URL is the request handler mapping to?), and a bit more of the home.html page would help.

Comment: @TedM.Young, I edited question as you suggested. I wanted to return home page with personal page as iframe-source in it from my login handler function.